# Calling all information populating a column

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on a button to email all users that have an email within the sqlite database. At the moment i have got the button working successfully, but can only call a single email address that is linked to the rows id.

Below is the code where i call upon the email and then send.

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btn_save).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View view ) { 
          Mail m = new Mail("gmail@gmail.com", "password"); 


          int arg = 0;

        String[] toArr = {user_eMail.get(arg)}; 
          m.setTo(toArr); 
          m.setFrom("gmail@gmail.com"); 
          m.setSubject("This email is never going to work"); 
          m.setBody("If you can read this email, please call me immediately because this never should have worked."); 

          try { 

            if(m.send()) { 
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else { 
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
          } catch(Exception e) { 
            //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
          } 
        } 
      });
```

How do i go about changing the "int arg = 0" into calling all ids in the database? If you need any other code just let me know.

Comment: `user_eMail.get` returns a single email. You need a function that returns a list.

Comment: user_eMail is defined as what kind of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, since `user_eMail` is an `ArrayList`

```
private ArrayList<String> user_eMail = new ArrayList<String>();
```

`.setTo()` method must receive an array of emails separated by ","

create a method to extract an array from the database (for example `getEmailsFromDB()`) containing the emails: `{"email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email3@gmail.com", "email4@gmail.com", "email5@gmail.com"};` 
and use:

```
m.setTo(getEmailsFromDB())
```

other option, the method returns from Database a String  containing all the emails separated by "," , like `"email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com, email3@gmail.com, email4@gmail.com, email5@gmail.com";`

```
String[] user_eMail = getEmailsFromDB().split(",");
m.setTo(user_eMail);
```

Comment: Im struggling to create the method to return the string containing all the emails. The query is very straight forward but im not sure how to create it within the method so that it can be called from the onClick? The user is able to add and delete email addresses as he pleases so unfortunately cant just hardcode the emails in.

Comment: Is this the type of method needed?                                private String getEmailsFromDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dataBase = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor Cursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT " + DbHelper.KEY_EMAIL + " FROM "
      + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
    
    
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(Cursor.moveToNext()){
        String usereMail = Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_EMAIL"));
        array.add(usereMail);
    }
    return null;
    
   } 
    });